# How can Shake FilePatterns be used to minify JS and CSS files?

Tags: javascript, css, haskell, minify, shake-build-system

Common practice with `.js` and `.css` file minification is to create `.min.js` and `.min.css` files. The problem is [Shake](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake) [FilePatterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.11.4/docs/Development-Shake.html#v%3a-63--61--61-) will match both minified and non-minified files with this scheme with a pattern like `//*.js`. The [docs](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/blob/master/docs/Manual.md#defining-rules) seem to recommend making unique extensions for each like `reg.js` and `min.js` but I'm not sure this is a path I want to take. How can this be worked around in Shake?

Edit: The problem is with using `getDirectoryFiles`:

```
js <- getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.js"]
let jsMins = map (-<.> "min" <.> "js") js
need jsMins
```

There's a target for `"//*.min.js` that works just fine but `getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.js"]` starts picking up the generated `.min.js` files.

Comment: You need a pattern that both rejects and accepts files based on their names (ie: a regex like `^.*(?<!\.min)\.js$`).  I'm pretty sure this can't be done with Shake FilePatterns since they only admit, but not reject files based on name.  Perhaps you can prefilter the list of files to exclude those with `".min."` in their name.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea is correct, the Shake FilePattern can't reject paths based on their name - it is a very restricted form of matching language.

Comment: @AlainO'Dea do you know how I can prefilter the pattern being sent to `getDirectoryFiles`? That's where the real problem is.

Comment: @LukeHoersten you can't pre-filter calls to `getDirectoryFiles` since takes a directory name and the `FilePattern`s and performs the lookup and filtering internally. You can post-filter the result of `getDirectoryFiles` just as you have shown in your edit above though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two alternative approaches:

**Post process `getDirectoryContents`**

Call `getDirectoryContents` then filter out the values you don't care about. Something like:

```
xs <- getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.js"]
need [x -<.> "min.js" | x <- xs, takeExtensions x == ".js"]
```

If you are running this code outside of a rule, e.g. in an `action`, then it is 100% correct. If you are running the code in a rule then the rule will run once, new files will appear, and then the rule will run again (which is also a lint violation, and not great build hygine). I suspect you are running outside of a rule, so this approach is probably a good one.

**Write an Oracle**

If you are inside a rule, you can define an Oracle which is like `getDirectoryFiles`, but skips the `min` files.

```
newtype JsFiles = JsFiles () deriving (Show,Typeable,Eq,Hashable,Binary,NFData)
addOracle $ \(JsFiles _) -> fmap (\x -> takeExtensions x == ".js") $ getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.js"]
```

Now you can use `askOracle $ JsFiles ()` in your rule, and it will only change when new non-`min` files are added.

Comment: So the key in the first approach is to run the getDirectoryFiles outside of a rule. I'm currently running it inside of a rule. That's my problem. Thanks a lot! Edit: I'm not sure I'm not in a rule. The `getDirectoryFiles` is on the right side of `*>` in this case.

Comment: Right hand side of `*>` is in a rule, so I recommend using the Oracle approach.

Comment: Looks like the oracle approach is having the same problem as the getDirectoryFiles approach. The linter is complaining the files are changing and it's giving inconsistent behavior between runs. Really what I need is a way to track `.js` files without tracking `.min.js` files. There must be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

There are several approaches to writing different generating rules for `.js` vs `.min.js`:

1. If you aren't ever generating `.js` or `.css` files, only using existing source files, and thus don't need `//*.js` rules, then just make your minimisation pattern be `//*.min.js` and it will work.
2. If you are generating `.js` (e.g. from CoffeeScript files), then if you are generating the `.min.js` and `.js` files in different directories you can distinguish the patterns at that level, e.g. `dist/*.min.js`, `decafinate/*.js`.
3. Use `?>` patterns, for example:

   `(\x -> takeExtensions x == ".js") ?> \out -> ...`

   Note that `takeExtensions` (with the trailing `s`), that will only match files whose complete extension is `.js`, so won't match `myfile/test.min.js`.

If solution 1 works, use that (it's simplest). If solution 2 naturally falls out (e.g. that matches what you wanted to do anyway) it can be easier to have more restrictive patterns, but option 3 "just works" everywhere so is probably what I'd do.

Note that `p *> a` is defined as `(p ?==) ?> a` (plus a lot of extra plumbing for good error messages!), so `?>` isn't anything special and works happily with your existing rules. I usually find about 5-10% of my rules use `?>` patterns.

Comment: #1 wont work for me because I use `js <- getDirectoryFiles "" ["//*.js"]` to get my js files, modify the names to `.min.js` then `need` them so the `//*.min.js` target runs. the problem is the getDirecoryFiles starts detecting the `.min.js` files. #3 might work though.

Comment: I think `getDirectoryFiles` might need the equivalent of `?>` for my issue to be resolved.

Comment: I've given a few `getDirectoryFiles` alternatives in another answer. You can't define `getDirectoryFiles` with an arbitrary predicate because that function runs when checking if a build is clean, so can't access functions inside rules. In contrast `?>` only runs when something is dirty, but even then it's not inside rules, but at the top level, making it easy to get at the function.